# Activity Monitor Problems in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions, cpu-usage, activity-monitor

I am looking at the Activty Monitor for SQL Server 2005 and we have some processes that are taking up large amounts of the CPU. When I look at what is trying to be run I get:

```
set transaction isolation level  read committed
```

This code is not coming from any of our applications.

What is causing it?

What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [sys.dm_exec_sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) and [sys.dm_exec_connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx) for the session ids that take up CPU. You'll find the application name, host name and process id of the client.

Comment: You can get all of those from the activity monitor. My question is what is causing this SQL to run because it is is using an exorbitant amount of CPU. So much so that it is causing problems.

Comment: Well then, *what* application is running these? The answer to your question is really dependent on finding out the origin of the queries first, don't you agree? Are they some sort of monitoring doing a too tight loop, are they some applications too many started, is there more to the requests than you posted?

Comment: The problem is that the the SQL above is being shown from multiple applications (all web apps). However, as stated in the question, those statements are not located in any code. Is this something that SQL Server could be doing?

Comment: No, SQL would not be running statements on its own. Those statements come from the web apps. They may not exist explicitly as SqlCommand text in your app, but there are several tens of thousands of lines of code from various frameworsk and ORMs between your code and what actually reaches SQL Server. A trivial example is the bening SqlConnection.Open() which sends a pretty hefty batch to initialize the session settings, a batch that ends in `set transaction isolation level read committed`...

Answer (score 0):

This is the default transaction isolation level for ADO.NET and most OR/M frameworks.  Chances are this is in fact coming for your code, you just don't know it.

I think this is the wrong question to ask anyways - the real question is, why is this rather common TSQL instruction causing your database CPU to spike?